# Why cant i update a textView in Activity - from a service

Tags: android

I have an activity named MainActivity and a service named MainService.

In mainActivity i have a button to start the MainService and a textView(lets say- txt1).

And in OnCreate() method of the service i have taken an instance of MainActivity and using that instance i am trying to update the txt1(TextView) of the activity- using setText. Even tried with post() method.

But its showing error. If i am not wrong than i think UI cant be updated from service. Or, i need to bind the service with the activity. right?

**So, my question is that why cant i update textView of activity from service?**

Comment: show us your relevant code pls

Comment: if u r updating textview in UI thread that only its ok....

Answer (score 0):

you probably can just not directly, if you create a callBack reference you can call a method in your activity from the service, but essentially the textView updates are run on the UI thread, so the actual update has to happen in the activity..

This might be helpful: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

1. sendBroadcast(intent) from service.
2. register receiver in your activity's onResume() and unregister the same in onPause().
3. Update textview in onReceive of BroadcastReceiver.